# Finding a Value in Culture Invariant/Case Invariant Way from a Dictionary<>

Tags: c#, dictionary

If I have a dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> cars = new Dictionary <string,List<string>>();

'importcar',    ['audi', 'bmw', 'mercedes']
'domesticcar',  ['chevy', 'mustang']
'truck',        ['ford', 'gmc', 'chevy', 'toyota']
```

how do I check if this dictionary has a string in its List values?

For the example above, how do I check if this dictionary has string 'chevy' (in above example, it has it for keys 'domesticcar' and 'truck') in an InvariantCulture and Ignored case?

I tried this and while it works, it doesn't seem to be elegant

```
// this will search for a car in dictionary under any key and find 1st occurance of it
// of it and remove it.  If List for the key is empty, it will remove the key as well.
foreach (var k in cars.Keys)
{
  bool found = false;

  List<string> ls = cars[k];  // get List for key
  if (ls.Contains("chevy", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    // get first occurance of car and remove it if found in list
    var car = ls.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Trim().ToLowerInvariant() == "chevy".Trim().ToLowerInvariant());
    if (car != null)
    {
      found = true;  //found 1st occurance of car in Dictionary, flag to exit loop
        ls.Remove(car);
    }
  }
  // remove key if its List<string> is empty
  if (ls.Count == 0)
  {
    cars.Remove(k);
  }

  if (found) break;
}
```

Comment: Are duplicates allowed in those lists?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains` in this way:

```cs
var keys = cars.Where(c => c.Value.Contains("chevy", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(a => a.Key);
```

//edit: I get a downvote? Of course you can use trim:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetKeys(Dictionary<string, List<string>> storage, string car)
{
    return storage.Where(c => c.Value.Contains(car.Trim(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(a => a.Key);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to do it the Linq way. Unfortunately, this solution needs a custom StringComparer to trim both values in the comparison, which may cut back on the "elegance". ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NIu9kt))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> cars = new Dictionary <string, List<string>>() {
                {"importcar",    new List<string>() {"audi", "bmw", "mercedes"}},
                {"domesticcar",  new List<string>() {"chevy", "mustang"}},
                {"truck", new List<string>(){"ford", "gmc", "chevy", "toyota"}}
            };
        var query = cars.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(" CHEVY", new TrimStringComparer())).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < query.Length; i++)
        {
            cars.Remove(query[i].Key);  
        }
        Console.WriteLine(cars.Count); //Or any other logic you need...
    }

}

class TrimStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<String> //Use this instead of StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase if you need to Trim() both values in the comparison
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Trim().ToLowerInvariant().Equals(y.Trim().ToLowerInvariant());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have no idea why someone would down-vote this???  Thanks @zambonee.  One comment though, I dont think you need to create new comparer if you use List<string> instead of your string[], you could just use StringComparer that already exists on Lists but nice you provided it, I think it is educative to see how to make one.  Appreciate!

Comment: @pixel it's that Trim() that requires a new comparer without using an overly complicated Linq statement.

Comment: Why are you using `ToLower()`?  Comparing values by changing case, especially for any type of globalization/localization is a [very bad idea](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/).

Comment: To everybody down-voting this, could you please comment as to why.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I am not using ToLower(), I am using ToLowerInvariant() which should be handling Turkish "i" properly if that is what you are referring to?  Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can trim

```
foreach (var k in cars.Keys)
{
    List<string> ls = cars[k];
    var car = ls.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ToLowerInvariant() == "chevy");
    if (car != null)
    {
        ls.Remove(car);
        if (ls.Count == 0)
        {
           cars.Remove(k);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I think you could do this with linq so

```
bool isOnInDictionary = cars.Any(s => s.Key == "truck");
```

I have not added all your string trim stuff to keep things clear.